# prevent updating some fields defined as filable on update a model

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose we have a model like this :

```
class BankAccount extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'rate', 'bank_id', 'account_number', 'active'];
{
```

As you can see there is a `$fillable` property.

When storing a new model I used these codes :

```
public function store(BankAccountFormRequest $request)
{

        BankAccount::create($request->all());
}
```

In this case a new `BankAccount` model created with fields that come from **request**.

But suppose in updating same model like this :

```
public function update(BankAccountFormRequest $request, $id)
{
    $bankAccount = BankAccount::findOrFail($id);
    $bankAccount->update($request->all());
}
```

In this case , I do not want to update some attributes that are fillable. for example I want to update just `title`, `rate` and I do not want  user can update other fields. but if User client send all fields as a request those fields will be update too.

Also I know that a way to solve the issue is use `save()` method like this :

```
public function update(BankAccountFormRequest $request, $id)
{
    $bankAccount = BankAccount::findOrFail($id);

    $bankAccount->user_id = $this->auth->user()->user_id;
    $bankAccount->accountable_id = $request->get('accountable_id');
    $bankAccount->accountable_type = $request->get('accountable_type');

    $bankAccount->save();

}
```

But I think that is not appropriate when count of desired columns to update is many.

What is real approach to solve that ?

Comment: use protected $guarded = ['column-name']; in your model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can user `$request->only` to filter parameters, optionally you can keep `['username', 'password']` as a static property of the model.

```
$request->only(['username', 'password']);
```

But inserting updating data directly from `$request->all()` will not be a good idea unless proper error handling is implemented. Eg, an extra parameter send in request will cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

As an enhancement for Jithin's answer:
You can define 'updatable' fields list in the Model.

```
 public function updatables(){
     return ['title','rate'];
 }
```

Then call it from Controller:

```
$bankAccount->update($request->only(BankAccount::updatables()));
```

Or do the opposite by defining the 'non updateables' and call

```
$bankAccount->update($request->except(BankAccount::nonUpdatables()));
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31093722)